# PyCharm keyword argument

Tags: python, pycharm

How to get PyCharm to show the keyword arguments while coding, like the options you can pick from? I can get VSCode to show this normally, but I just can't figure out how to get PyCharm to do it. You'll see the difference in the screenshots. One is from PyCharm and the other one is from VSCode

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Why you should not upload code/data/errors as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) (and if you feel the images add something to the code you've also provided, you better make sure the link actually works...)

Comment: It's funny that you link me to something irrelevant to what I'm asking. If you learned to actually read what kind of help I'm looking for you wouldn't have tried to be smart with me. Also the links work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start a new project in PyCharm, add a .py file and entire the following code:

```
import os

os.chdir()
```

And you position the cursor between the two parentheses while typing, or when you press `Ctrl+P` in that position, PyCharm will show a hint saying "`path: int | str | bytes | PathLike[str] | PathLike[bytes]`", like this:

[image: PyCharm Screenshot]

If you're just looking for the autocomplete, instead of the type hints, similarly ensure you're typing something that *could* be completed and PyCharm wil show type hints you can navigate with arrow keys (or can just complete by hitting Enter).

[image: PyCharm UI screenshot showing autocomplete]

Note that you can cause PyCharm to show it again by hitting `Ctrl+Space`.

Mind you, if you type something that has no logical completion (i.e. nothing starts with the string you've written so far), there is no autocompletion, and so none is shown - instead PyCharm will show a small message in its place saying 'no suggestions'.

Comment: Tyty that's pretty helpful

Comment: If it answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark, so your question no longer appears as unanswered - if it doesn't solve the problem, feel free to leave a comment saying what problems remain.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. I want an autocomplete option like how VSCode gives it compared to Pycharm. I'm not sure if Pycharm supports it or not. Showing that as an option is nice and all, but doesn't show/tell me if Pycharm has that same capability as VSCode as to where I can just press "enter" to autocomplete it. Looking for a straight yes or no. Then I can say this has been answered.

Comment: The answer is yes - see the edit in the answer (and use `Ctrl+Space` to show it when it happens to close due to your actions.